# iOS - UIImage with alpha has washed-out colors in MKOverlayRenderer on iOS13

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, mkmapview, alpha

I have `MKOverlayRenderer` with RGBA `UIImage` loaded from PNG. The image has alpha values 0 for transparent parts and 160 for semi-transparent ones.

However, when I render the image on the map, the colors are sort-of washed out and the entire image looks like behind fog. This issue happened after update to iOS 13, older versions are working as expected.

I load image via `[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_img"];`

I have extend `MKOverlayRenderer`, and override `drawMapRect` method:

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context { 
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_img"];

    MKMapRect theMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect;
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, img.CGImage);
}
```

I have tried to manually remove premultiplied alpha (set alpha to 255 instead of 160) from the image by creating its copy and processing RGBA pixels manually with this formula:

```
CGImageRef sourceImage = img.CGImage;

CFDataRef theData;
theData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(sourceImage));

UInt8 *pixelData = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(theData);

int dataLength = CFDataGetLength(theData);

for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i += 4){
   uint8_t aHalf = pixelData[i + 3] / 2;
   pixelData[i + 0] = (pixelData[i + 0] * 255 + aHalf) / pixelData[i + 3];
   pixelData[i + 1] = (pixelData[i + 1] * 255 + aHalf) / pixelData[i + 3];
   pixelData[i + 2] = (pixelData[i + 2] * 255 + aHalf) / pixelData[i + 3];        
   pixelData[i + 3] = (pixelData[i + 3] == 0) ? 0 : 255;
}

CGContextRef context;
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData,
                                CGImageGetWidth(sourceImage),
                                CGImageGetHeight(sourceImage),
                                8,
                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow(sourceImage),
                                CGImageGetColorSpace(sourceImage),
                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];
```

Then I set `CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.6);` in `drawMapRect`.

This partially fixed the issue, but on older iOS versions, the image is less transparent than on iOS 13, plus entire process takes time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the same issue:

Apples response is that this is due to a change in the color space of the CGContext in the renderer. In iOS 12 an RGB color space was used, but iOS 13 is now using a Linear sRGB color space.

I was able to convert my source images to use Linear sRGB with ImageMagick, and they now show the correct shade when rendered transparent. I'm not sure if you own the source images, and can convert them, but if you can that should solve your problem.

Comment: sRGB is non-linear. So I am not sure what is meant by Linear sRGB. Do you have a reference to what was said by Apple?

Comment: @fmw42 Here's the quote from Apple Developer Technical Support:

"The color space on the CGContext passed to your overlay renderer has changed — it was the device’s RGB color space on iOS 12, but with iOS 13, it is now using a Linear sRGB color space. The easiest thing for you to do is to create an updated map image that uses a Linear sRGB color space and load that image on iOS 13, but maintain your existing image for iOS 12."

I'll admit that my knowledge of this is super limited, and it appears that the Apple Engineer might have added an "s" accidentally.

Comment: I do not understand what a linear sRGB is? sRGB by nature is non-linear. Sorry, I do not think I can help further.